# Isabelle book Exercise 2.11: Transforming expressions to polynomial form

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

my question is concerning Exercise 2.11 in the book Concrete Semantics (http://concrete-semantics.org/):

Define arithmetic expressions in one variable over integers
(type `int`) as a data type:

```
datatype exp = Var | Const int | Add exp exp | Mult exp exp
```

Define a function `eval :: exp => int => int` such that `eval e x` evaluates e at
the value x.
A polynomial can be represented as a list of coefficients, starting with the
constant. For example, [4, 2, -1, 3] represents the polynomial `4+2x-x^2+3x^3`.

Define a function `evalp :: int list => int => int` that evaluates a polynomial at
the given value. Define a function `coeffs :: exp => int list` that transforms an
expression into a polynomial. This may require auxiliary functions. Prove that
coeffs preserves the value of the expression: `evalp (coeffs e) x = eval e x`.

---end

It's all pretty straightforward until you get to `coeffs`. We would have to deal with expressions like `(X + X)*(2*X + 3*X*X)` which have to be recursively expanded bottom-up using a distributive law until its in polynomial form. The resulting expression might still be something like `(X*X + X*2*X + 3*X*X + 4*X*X*X)` so then its necessary to normalize product terms (so eg `X*2*X` becomes `2*X*X`), collect together like terms, and finally order them in order of increasing degree! This just seems significantly more complicated than any of the exercises so far that I wonder if I'm missing something or overly complicating it.

Answer (score 4):

I think this exercise is considerably easier than you think. You can write a single primitively-recursive function `coeffs` that does the job: the coefficients of `Var` are `[0,1]`, the coefficients of `Const c` are `[c]`. Similarly, if you have two subexpressions and you know their coefficients, you can combine those two coefficient lists into a single list for addition/multiplication.

For that, you should ideally write two auxiliary functions `add_coeffs` and `mult_coeffs` which add and multiply two lists of coefficients. (the latter will probably make use of the former)

You will have to prove that `add_coeffs` and `mult_coeffs` do the right thing (w.r.t. `eval` and `evalp`). The resulting lemmas also make good `[simp]` rules.

The proofs are all simple inductions where each case is automatic.

As a general rule: a good definition often makes the difference between a long and tedious proof and a straight-forward or even completely automatic proof. Doing a long-winded expansion and then grouping summands etc. as you suggested in your question is sure to lead to a tedious proof.

Of course, the method that I suggested in this answer is not very efficient, but when you want to do things in a theorem prover, efficiency is usually not a big concern – you want things to be simple and elegant and amenable to nice proofs. If you need efficient code, you can still develop your nice and simple abstract formulation into something more efficient later and show equivalence.